# ASP.NET MVC - Change BG Color of a table if a boolean property is set as false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

How would I do to change the color of the table row when my "Active" property is  switch to false?

I do not use the "Active" property in the table because it does not make sense. So how would I do to check if the property is false and with that change the color of the table?

My ViewModel

```
 public class CodigosDeOperacaoViewModel
  {
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Campo Obrigatório")]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Code{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
    public string Description{ get; set; }

   [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
   public bool Active{ get; set; }
  }
```

MyView

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>

        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }   
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view model is a bit strange and the code you posted won't work. You will need to update it so that it contains data about your rows. Something like this

```
 public class CodigosDeOperacaoViewModel
 { 
   //ROWs data
   public ICollection<RowData> RowItems {get;set;}
}

public class RowData
 {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage ="Campo Obrigatório")]
   [MaxLength(10)]
   public string Code{ get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
   public string Description{ get; set; }

   [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
   public bool Active{ get; set; }
}



<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        Code
    </th>
    <th>
        Description
    </th>

    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.RowItems)
{
<tr @(item.Active? "active": string.Empty)>
    <td>
        @Html.Display(item.Code)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.Display(item.Description)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```